# Make span come before text in Jade

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, pug

I'm working on a navbar and I'm trying to have a button on the bar be in the format:

(icon)(text)

Here's the excerpt from the jade file:

```
a(href="/signup")
  h3 Sign Up  
    span(style="font-size: 1.25em; margin-top:2%" href="/graphing").glyphicon.glyphicon-pencil
```

Currently this produces:

(text)(icon)

How can I have it so the span is inside the h3, but is BEFORE the text in jade?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a piped text:

```
a(href="/signup")
  h3
    span(style="font-size: 1.25em; margin-top:2%" href="/graphing").glyphicon.glyphicon-pencil
    | Sign Up
```

---

From [The documentation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#pipedtext):

> **Piped Text**
>
> The simplest way of adding plain text to templates is to prefix the line with a | character (pronounced "pipe").

Comment: Non-intuitive for me, but worked nevertheless!